# How can i make activity to be displayed on desired part of the screen like the activity is displayed in fallowing photo?

Tags: android

[Activity displayed on some part of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctLg9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a little vague, but if you are referring to the image placement:

First find the width of the device screen:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int screen_width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

Then you can position the Image based off screen_width.

For example, if you wanted it centered:

```
Say the width of the Image is 720. Then:

my_background_image.setX( (int)(screen_width/720) /2 );
```

Otherwise, if you are referring to the activity itself, then you would position it in your res/layout/[your activity].xml.

Depends on your layout. Constrained, linear, etc.

Can you be more specific?

Comment: can u please visit the fallowing link to be more specific and check Filter section specificly. Thanks in advance. https://yalantis.com/blog/top-design-solutions-for-ecommerce-apps/